# How can I fix my partition table? (two grubs)

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, kubuntu

I was once foolish enough to think I would take care of my Ubuntu install ("this time I will, I promise...") so I didn't separate /home or anything when I installed it for the first time. Now I kind of want to leave some bloat behind.

I've installed Kubuntu 15.10 (guided install). The problem is I don't think GRUB was installed correctly. The GRUB I get when I turn the laptop on is the one from my *previous* Ubuntu install (I had to update-grub so I could log into my new Kubuntu install). The partition table is weird because I have this fat32 space flagged as "boot" and "esp", and this "unknown" partition flagged as "bios_grub". I suspect the fat32 one is the grub that's actually being used and this unknown one was supposed to be the new grub. Funny thing is I've already 'grub-install'ed from the new Kubuntu system and nothing changed.

With time I'll move the data over to a new partition, using it as some sort of /home partition... But for now all I want is to solve this Grub mess. How do I use the grub from my new install, so that I can delete the original system without worrying?

This is the layout so to make it clearer:

[image: GParted layout (annotated)]

Thanks in advance; any help is appreciated - I've read a lot about EFI and MBR and GPT and other three-or-four-letter things and I am now more confused than ever.

Comment: I know you've figured this out, but for future reference, you've created a mixed-mode (EFI/UEFI and BIOS/CSM/legacy) set of installations. This is almost certain to create headaches, and so should be avoided. In your case, it's best avoided by entering your firmware and disabling the CSM (aka "legacy boot" support). See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for more on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a lot of research and help from the G+ community (special thanks to Sanja Bonic!) I figured out what to do.

Basically, the sda1 partition was the EFI partition, and every drive from newer PCs, like those that come with Windows 8, has to have one (I'm leaning towards saying *only* one). So I kept using that as my EFI partition.

I'll use a lot of stuff from [this website](https://superuser.com/questions/376470/how-to-reinstall-grub2-efi), one you should refer to if you find yourself in a similar situation.

Anyway: I live-booted Xubuntu into my system (like he says in the website, you have to boot it as a UEFI system). Then you chroot into your own system (in my case, the new one; the sda5 in the gparted image). To do that, execute these commands:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

(replace sda2 with your system partition)

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi
```

(replace sda1 with your EFI partition)
(notice your system might not have a "efi" folder inside boot; I created one with 'sudo mkdir /mnt/boot/efi' and things worked out fine!)

```
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done

sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/
```

(This one makes the network available after chrooting)

```
modprobe efivars

sudo chroot /mnt
```

Now since I was in Xubuntu (Ubuntu-based system) I had to do an 'apt-get' command:

```
apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64
```

Now we're going to undo the chrooting and all the mounting.

**Type Ctrl+D**

And then these commands:

```
for i in /sys /proc /dev/pts /dev; do sudo umount /mnt$i; done
sudo umount /mnt/boot/efi
sudo umount /mnt
sudo reboot
```

... And that's it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` to set the boot flag for the correct partition.

If you press 'a' it will ask you to select the partition you want to toggle the boot flag on. In your case, you want to toggle 1 (to unset) and 5 to set.

I hope it helps and be extra careful with fdisk !

Comment: What about that unknown partition, though? Do you think it could be safely deleted?

Comment: If your system boots correctly from the sda5 you can delete it but it is not worth bothering as I can see you have already a huge hard drive. You may want to merge sda1 and sda2 in a future upgrade at some point.

Comment: Harris, I'm upvoting because you were trying to help and I appreciate that :) however, I don't know if that way of doing things was viable (because apparently GPT drives can't be tinkered with by fdisk). Thanks a lot, however! I'll reply my own question with what I did.

Comment: The disk in question is clearly a GPT disk. Although `fdisk` in Ubuntu 15.10 finally supports GPT, the actions you describe will not work on a GPT disk, and even the underlying premise of an "active/boot" partition does not apply to GPT -- at least, not in the same way it does to an MBR disk that boots in BIOS mode.